# How to display a value according to min and max position from a json array in AngularJS and Ionic v1

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, scope, controller

I develop a mobile banking application using Ionic v1. I have a form for making a withdraw. I want when the user enter any amount, it display automatically in the html view, the cost for this amount.

and my json array look like this:

```
$scope.rateWithdraw = [
    {min: 0.10, max: 5, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 0.60, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class1'},
    {min: 5.01, max: 10, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 0.65, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class2'},
    {min: 10.01, max: 20, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 0.70, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class3'},
    {min: 20.01, max: 50, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 0.75, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class4'},
    {min: 50.01, max:  100, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 1.25, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class5'},
    {min: 100.01, max: 200, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 2, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class6'},
    {min: 200.01, max: 300, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 3, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class7'},
    {min: 300.01, max: 400, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 4, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class8'},
    {min: 400.01, max: 1000, transtype: 'WITHDRAW', value: 5, currency: 'USD', comment: 'class9'}
];
```

Example, if the user types in the form an amount which is equal to 24$, the application must located in which interval, the amount is located (In occurrence min: 20.01, max: 50) and display the cost for it (in occurrence, value: 0.75$). Help me please, because Im a beginner in ionic and angularJS

Comment: So, what have you tried, and what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: i didnt try something, im a beginer

Comment: Ah. Then the proper way of doing is to read documentation, examples, tutorials, books, and try something. Not to ask for help.

Comment: so i really dont have any idea

Comment: Okay, my brother im trying something just now

Comment: can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this.

```
$scope.amount = null; //amount will come from the user through form 

angular.forEach($scope.rateWithdraw, function($scope.amount){

    if($scope.amount >= $scope.rateWithdraw.min && $scope.amount <= $scope.rateWithdraw.max){

         console.log($scope.rateWithdraw.value); //just for testing
    }                   

});
```